# Edit wordpress files in Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers

I have this docker-file

```
services:
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

I run this and install WordPress but I want to learn to make templates and plugins so I need to edit WP files. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

After starting your containers using the compose file:

1. List the running containers: `docker ps`
2. Check which of the running containers has the image as `wordpress:latest` and copy the id of the container associated with it
3. Enter the container by running `docker exec -it  <you-container-id> /bin/sh`

And now you have a session inside of the container. You can edit the files inside with vi (not the most ideal).
Look up docker volumes if you want to edit the files locally and have them be mapped inside of the containers.

Comment: OK, I know but I want to use VSC to programming. Is it possible to mapping WP folder with folder in my computer? Maybe I should modify docker-compose?